# Sorting data over array length

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to sort my retrieve with descending. How can I handle it with $exists:true command? I want to sort over the array length.

**MongoDB**

```
{ 
    "likelist" : [ 
        "5778173453f8f28a119d6eaa", 
        "5778173453f8f28a119d6eab" 
    ], 
    "unlikelist" : [ 
        "57781e7978ac42eb027d3728" 
    ] 
}
```

**Node.js**

```
Data.find({
    $and: [ 
        query, 
        { "likelist": { $exists: true } }
    ]
}).limit(req.body.limit).lean().exec(function (err,data) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

Comment: why dont you you use `.sort({"_id":1})`

Comment: Because I want to sort over the array length. The highest first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe something like this would work

```
Data.find({
    $and: [ 
        query, 
        { "likelist": { $exists: true } }
    ]
}).sort({"_id":1}).limit(req.body.limit).lean().exec(function (err,data) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

if you want something else then please do tell

Note: **The relationship between the order of ObjectId values and generation time is not strict within a single second**

Fore information read this : http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification

Comment: Hi, I want to sort over the array length. With _id:1 it will not work.

Comment: that is not possible, atleast not over multiple fields